# How can you import Tasks from TFS into VS Studio Project Task List?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, tfs

I would like to be able to import TFS tasks / work items into the Visual Studio Task Lists.  Is this possible?

UPDATE:

It looks as though I'll have to use WIQL that is found in the [SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsx/default.aspx).  I hope to save some time and would appreciate any posts / war stories associated with TFS and sync'ing to Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this is not possible with the current tool set.  The supported way of viewing WorkItem's is through the various query views.

It wouldn't be too much work though to create an add-in which pushed a set of WorkItems into the task list though.

Comment: Thanks.  Do you know of a link / post that points to appropriate VS API to make this work?